# How to uninstall VS code completely from manjaro linux, when terminal doesn't see it at all?

Tags: visual-studio-code, uninstallation

I am  very new here, and also in programming.
I have found out that I have VS Code two times installed with different ways. When I started it from the KDE it ran well, but when I have started it from the current directory with "code ." it was an oss version without some extension and accounts.
Now I want to uninstall completely both of them. One version I could from terminal with yay --remove code. So the terminal can't see any versoion of vs code any more. But in the application launcher is vs code still there, I can run it and use completely. But I have no idea how to uninstall it.
I have already tried this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/uninstall

Answer (score 0):

you can uninstall from manjaro linux by visiting the add software>installed>code and clicking the trashcan near the name of the software. this will queue the action of deletion. Now just click apply on the bottom right of the screen and confirm all the things it will ask you. then it will uninstall code.

Answer (score 0):

So I also had this problem, I found this command for uninstall vs code,

```
sudo pacman -R visual-studio-code-bin
```